# Sometimes the wrong svg is embeded. Using react-inlinesvg in project React / Redux / Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, inline-svg

This is a wierd one and i'm having problems to find a possible solution.

I'm working on a React/Redux/Webpack project and we are using `react-inlinesvg` to handle the svg's.

**The Problem:**

Sometimes the app that i'm working on, renders the wrong svg. Here is an img with an example:

[Example of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIhJY.png)

The correct icons are the ones on the top layer and on the bottom (A Edit and a Close/Erase button) But if you look at the layer in the middle the icons that are rendered aren't the right ones.

**Important info:**

I can reproduce this behavior if I do an action that updates the component where the svg icons appear, but not all appear wrong, just 1 or 2 random divs. If I refresh the page the icons show the right way.

Here is the component that uses the react-inlinesvg:

```
import React from 'react';
import InlineSVG from 'react-inlinesvg';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export default class Icon extends React.Component {

    render () {

        var IconClass = classnames('Icon', this.props.name);
        var iconSrc = '/stylesheets/assets/icon-' + this.props.name + '.svg';

        return (
            <span className={IconClass} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                <InlineSVG key={this.props.name} cacheGetRequests={true} wrapper={React.DOM.i} src={iconSrc} />
            </span>
        );
    }
}

Icon.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.oneOf([
        'close',
        'trash',
        'edit',
        'download',
        'thumbsup',
        'thumbsdown',
         etc...
    ])
};
```

I would like to ask you help to understand why this may be happening and possible solutions?

Is it something about the way react updates the components? Any server problem/slowness?

What other info can I give you to help you help me?

**Thanks for your time and help!**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and comes from how `react-inlinesvg` is using the `shouldComponentUpdate`. Basically it is not re-rendering if the `src` change. You can try by randomizing the `key`. Personally I switched to `react-svg`

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly. How could I do that randomizing of the key? 

I will check the `react-svg` to see if it works. At first glance it doesn't have props that the other has like the `cacheGetRequests` and the `wrapper`, how did you handled that?

Comment: @pmrgnogueira I guess a `Math.random` will do the trick, but it also probably harms the performance. You can also pass the `src` as key as well.